# Jquery Selector using eq() with filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, filter

I would like to know if it is possible to use eq() with filter(). I've already tested it and to no avail, though I've found a work around. I was just wondering in case I missed something.

My example is this...
Say you have a few tables with columns and rows.

```
<table class="menuTable"><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table>
<table class="menuTable"><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table>
```

I would like to find how many column spaces are in each table, so...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert($(".menuTable").eq(0).filter("td").length);
alert($(".menuTable").eq(1).filter("td").length);
</script>
```

This doesn't work and I'd like to find out why. I ended up using .find() instead of .filter(), but I think it would be more appropriate to use .filter().

Thanks for any input.

After a few comments I realize my problem is in the difference between find and filter. Also... for those who are curious. I did manage to get it to work using filter by including eq in the selector...

```
alert($(".menuTable:eq(0)").filter("td").length);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I ended up using .find() instead of .filter(), but I think it would be
>   more appropriate to use .filter().

`find` is indeed what you should be using here. `filter` as the name suggests, filters the collection of elements, in your case that collection is all `.menuTable` elements; there are no `td`s in that collection. `find` on the other hand looks for children elements, and your collection *does* have `td` children elements.

Comment: Ok. I see what you're saying. Thanks for the explanation. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` filters the already selected elements, what you're looking for is `find()`, which finds elements within the selected elements, and that would in fact be the correct method to use for this!

```
alert($(".menuTable").eq(0).find("td").length);
```

Comment: That's interesting, because I was able to successfully use eq(), but only if I included it in the statement such as: alert($(".menuTable:eq(0)").filter("td").length);

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean find out how many columns are in each table (not sure what "column spaces" means)? You can use `find` in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($(".menuTable").eq(0).find("td").length);
    alert($(".menuTable").eq(1).find("td").length);
});
```

If you use a good JavaScript debugger (like in Chrome) or log to console, you can see that `$('.menuTable').eq(0)` is going to return the first table matched. Applying [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to that doesn't make sense -- it would make sense if you used `find('td')` and then wanted to filter the `td` elements based on say a class attribute.

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5M8Zx/)

Comment: I'm referring to 'td' spaces. Why doesn't it make sense? In that case I don't understand the difference between filter and find. I thought filter reduced the amount of results. Since there are two tables, I narrow it down, and then I want to further filter to find only the td. Could you explain the difference

Comment: A jQuery selector like `$('table')` would find all the tables. If you ran `$('table').filter()` the `filter` would be operating on that set of tables. You would use `filter` to get a table that matches a specific thing like "has a class X". You want the children of the table which in relation to the table is table > tbody > tr > td. Does that start to make sense? I'm trying to figure out how else to word it. Reading the [jQuery entry for filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) would be a good idea.